# how to make rounded or custom border radius css

Tags: css

I was searching for website references and found a website with a cool image header.
here is the image header from the website
[image]

It has border-radius on the bottom left and bottom right corner, so make the image looks so cool.
I've tried using border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius. but it doesn't look the same. here is code that I've tried

```
#image-header{
   height:100px;
   width:500px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
   background:green;
}
```

Can I achieve this only using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```css
#image-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 60% / 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-header"></div>
```

Try adjusting the percentage values, in the `border-radius` property until you get your desired results.

Comment: wow thankyou, this is what i'm looking for. thankyouuu <3

Comment: Glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a divider below the header box and add border-radius to that divider:

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.header-bottom {
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh</p>
</div>

<div class="header-bottom"></div>
```